# How to catch Bootstrap navbar dropdown event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, events

I'm using the basic Twitter Bootstrap navbar for my menu, and I now want to show notifications in a dropdown inspired by the system here on Stackoverflow. To accomplish this I want to call the api when clicking the dropdown, for which I need to "catch" the dropdown event. According to [the docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns-events), I need to catch the event like so:

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

So I've got a [working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gru70kcs/), but when I use the exact same code in my own html (see below) it doesn't work anymore. Does anybody know what's wrong with the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#jajaja').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
            alert('Come on lets show the dropdown!!');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">My Website</a>
                </div>
                <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="jajaja">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="" id="notifications-header" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Notifications <span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul id="notifications" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh text-center" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: perhaps add a jQuery document ready around your JavaScript, e.g. `$(function() { ...your code ... }`. The `#jajaja` element isn't in the dom yet when your JavaScript is executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Why it does work in the jsfiddle?

This is because you load the javascript code using onload. See the onload selection in the dropdown left.

### Why doesn't it work on my website?

Because you place the code in the head and you don't wait till the dom is ready.

### How can I fix this?

Check if the dom is ready. Can be done like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#jajaja').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
        alert('Come on lets show the dropdown!!');
    });
});
```

Or in short:

```
$(function() {
    $('#jajaja').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
        alert('Come on lets show the dropdown!!');
    });
});
```

Other good practice is placing all javascript just before closing the body `</body>`.

Comment: How stupid of me. I've just wasted way too much time on this. Thanks a million!

Comment: for me alert is coming 2 times on each click, how can I trace the issue